# useEffect run count with dependency list

Tags: reactjs

I want to get a verification on how exactly useEffect runs when it has a dependency list.

Quoting the official react docs:

> By default, effects run after every completed render, but you can choose to fire them only when certain values have changed.
>
> The default behavior for effects is to fire the effect after every completed render. That way an effect is always recreated if one of its dependencies changes.

But it seems to me the correct wording would be that the effect runs initially always and then only runs when one of it's dependencies change. In other words if I put a useEffect into a component it is guaranteed that it will run after the initial render no matter what and I can opt-in what will happen afterwards with the dependency list. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Yes, that's another wording for what is written.

Comment: React hooks are ***always*** called after every render, in the same order they are defined. What you describe is not an assumption, it's what the docs say. I think the official docs are clear enough, but yes, the `useEffect` hook callback will be invoked at least once when the component mounts, then subsequently only if a dependency updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you were right I tried it out with a `useEffect` in a example. The docs say that `useEffect` runs after completion of each render and so your words are correct and explain it better.

You can checkout a [working codesandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-leaf-gefwy?file=/src/App.js)

My code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("started");
    console.log("changed the val to =>", val);
  }, [val]);

  const changehandler = () => {
    setVal(2);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>bla cool</h1>
      <button onClick={changehandler}>change</button>
      <h1>{val}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here I console log "started" in the `useEffect` with a dependency of `val` and it gets logged when the app loads.